# mySQL search with datatables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I am searching data in mySql with DataTables and CodeIgntier,

below is controller search loop and model,

**Controller search building**

```
    if (isset($searchValue) && $searchValue != '')
    {
        $searching = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<count($columns); $i++) //Loop search in all defined columns
        {
            $searching = $this->db->or_like($columns[$i], $searchValue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $searching = NULL;
    }

$this->model->get_myreports($this->session->userdata('user_id'), $searching);
```

**Model function,**

```
public function get_myreports($user_id, $searching)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $searching;
    return $this->db->get('reports')->result_array();
}
```

Which in turn results  to below sql query,

```
SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE `report_id` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_name` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_submitted` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_total` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_status` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_received` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' AND `user_id` = '4' ORDER BY `report_status` DESC, `report_id` LIMIT 10
```

Now problem is,

it is showing all users reports while doing search, even i told to search with user_id = 4, it shows reports of user_id = 1 as well, while doing search only,
In normal `datatables` while page load, it shows correct reports of user_id = 4, but problem is in search query only,

How can i search for only `user_id = 4` ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
public function get_myreports($user_id, $searching)
{
   $this->db->->group_start()       
   ->or_like($searching)
   ->group_end()
   ->where('user_id', $user_id);
   return $this->db->get('reports')->result_array();
}
```

Comment: I am almost there, but it created something like this, it is adding only bracets with one AND.......SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE `report_id` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' ' OR `report_received` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' AND ( ) AND `user_id` = '4' ORDER BY `report_status` DESC, `report_id` LIMIT 10

Comment: `$searching = $this->db->or_like($columns[$i], $searchValue);` should be like an array, then the or_like will do the grouping task of paranthesis:

`$searching[$columns[$i]] =  $searchValue;`

Comment: one more problem now, when i remove all keyword for searching, now it show error in datatable, because search could not complete,.....SELECT * FROM `ec_reports` WHERE ( LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' ) AND `user_id` = '4' ORDER BY `report_status` DESC, `report_id` LIMIT 10

Comment: add an `IF` condition such as `if($searching != NULL) { ... } else{ .. only where user_id clause...no grouping is required}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Add the brackets for whole or case

```
SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE (`report_id` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_name` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_submitted` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_total` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_status` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_received` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!') AND (`user_id` = '4') ORDER BY `report_status` DESC, `report_id` LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

May be query like this. add () brackets in searching.

```
SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE (`report_id` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_name` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_submitted` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_total` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_status` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_received` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!') AND `user_id` = '4' ORDER BY `report_status` DESC, `report_id` LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Ok, then now i need see how can i build brackets in CI framework query

Comment: $this->model->get_myreports($this->session->userdata('user_id'), '('.$searching.')'); using concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->model->get_myreports($this->session->userdata('user_i‌​d'), '('.$searching.')');

SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE (`report_id` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_name` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_submitted` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_total` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_status` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!' OR `report_received` LIKE '%sup%' ESCAPE '!') AND `user_id` = '4' ORDER BY `report_status` DESC, `report_id` LIMIT 10
```